# Riemann manifold with unbounded Laplacian

Tags: operator-theory, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

How can one characterize a Riemann manifold the Laplacian of which is unbounded? (Equivalently, what are those manifolds on which the Laplacian is bounded? I am interested in working with its exponential.)

Comment: on which spaces (target and source) do you consider the Laplacian?

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian should essentially always be unbounded in the sense that its eigenvalues are unbounded. Loosely, one can think of eigenvalues of the Laplacian as frequencies at which waves can propagate in the manifold, and it's not surprising that waves can propagate at arbitrarily high frequencies.

More precisely, on a compact Riemannian $d$-manifold, [Weyl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law) implies that the $n^{th}$ eigenvalue of the Laplacian grows in absolute value something like $O(n^{2/d})$. For example, on $S^1$ the $n^{th}$ eigenvalue has absolute value $n^2$.

However, one can make sense of the exponential $e^{t \Delta}$ when $t$ is positive (here by $\Delta$ I mean the negative-semidefinite Laplacian). See [heat kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel) for some details.

Comment: Haha, this is funny: my question was motivated by precisely the need to understand the heat kernel on (not necessarily compact) manifolds (and a few things beyond). Ok, let me be blunt: how does one define the exponential of the Laplacian? In particular, would it make sense to define it on Schwartz distributions? Distributions form a locally-convex space, so not having a norm might not help me with the convergence of the Taylor series of the exponential function. The trouble is that most textbooks cheat: they either work in $L^2$, or on compact (or at least complete) manifolds. I want more!

Comment: @Alex: one option you have is to define it on eigenfunctions of the Laplacian in the obvious way and then appeal to elliptic regularity (I guess this requires compactness). Is this what you mean by cheating? In general, I dunno. (I do think it's good to ask the question you actually want to know the answer to!)